# How to compare Two data stores in Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have two data store of type `dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore`.One of the data store having old data and other one having new data.How can i compare these two data stores?

I call the fetch method on both of the stores and did a compare but didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF a same item can be in two stores, then you could fetch all items from one store, on Complete, foreach item, otherStore.isItem(someItem) which will return a boolean :)
Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

```
The format used by ItemFileReadStore is not a requirement of the dojo.data API. The
format it uses is designed to work well for the specific situations 
ItemFileReadStore is  used for, which are moderately sized data sets that can be easily
represented in a JavaScript Object tree.
```

### **Structure of Input Data Format**

```
  {
 "label": "some attribute",   // Optional attribute used to indicate which attribute on
  an item should act as a human-readable label for display purposes.

 "identifier": "some attribute",  // Optional attribute used to indicate which  
  attribute on an item acts as a unique identifier for that item. If it is not defined,  
  then the ItemFileReadStore will simply number the items and use that number as a
  unique index to the item.
 "items:" [  // The array of JavaScript objects that act as the root items of the data 
  store
  { /* Some set of name/value attributes */ },
  { /* ... */ },
    ...
  ]
  }
```

Comment: This not at all answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

**solution 1:** in our application we have used this method:

```
dojo.require("dojo.json");
_equal: function(objA, objB) {
    return dojo.json.stringify(objA) === dojo.json.stringify(objB);
}
```

the data inside objects should also have the same order, otherwise comparison will fail.

**solution 2:** but in dojo 1.8 they have introduced [`dojox/mvc/equals`](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mvc/equals.html) function.
it compares two given objects.

please also consider using `dojo/store` instead of deprecated `dojo/data`